# Inconsistent accesibility Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

My errors:

> `Error    1   Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MvcMusicStore.Models.OrderDetail>' is less accessible than property 'MvcMusicStore.Models.MusicStoreEntities.OrderDetails'  C:\Users\Jose\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MvcMusicStore\Models\MusicStoreEntities.cs  19  35  MvcMusicStore`
>
> `Error    2   Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcMusicStore.Models.OrderDetail>' is less accessible than property 'MvcMusicStore.Models.Order.OrderDetails'    C:\Users\Jose\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\MvcMusicStore\Models\Order.cs   25  32  MvcMusicStore`

My code causing these errors:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }<<<<<ERROR
```

The other error is at

```
public class MusicStoreEntities:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artist { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }<<<<<<ERROR

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MvcMusicStore.Models.Artist> Artists { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both errors mean the same thing: the type parameters of the generic types `List` and `DbSet`, i.e. `OrderDetail` and `MvcMusicStore.Models.Artist` are not marked public in your code, making their visibility internal to your package. This implies that these types cannot be used in `public` properties.

There are two ways of fixing this:

- You can make the types `public`, or
- You can make the properties `internal`.

Which course of action to choose depends on the accessibility requirements of `OrderDetails` and `Artists` in your project.

Answer (score 1):

To be more concise your error pinpoints OrderDetails and that's where you ought to correct.
Please check your class **OrderDetail** it begins as:
class OrderDetail
Pre-append public so that it appears as:
public class OrderDetail